# How to get Yammer conversation for a given URL

Tags: yammer

I'm using Yammer Embed control to allow users to create new discussions for pages they are on.
I'm doing this with this code:

```
var objectUrl = window.location.href;

yam.connect.embedFeed(
    {
        container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'my.network',
        feedType: 'open-graph',
        feedId: '',
        objectProperties: {
            url: objectUrl,
            type: 'page'
        },
        config: {
            defaultGroupId: 1234
        }
    });
```

I need to build a component, which aggregates conversations related to all my application pages. Is there a way to check if a conversation exists for a given URL and retrieve its messages?

Answer (score 0):

Yammer Embed is the only supported way to get a roll-up of all conversations around a specific URL. There is currently no supported, or documented way to get these conversations separately from Embed.

Comment: I used a method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869182/can-i-get-open-graph-page-with-feed-from-the-api?rq=1
I don't see this endpoint in the documentations, any reasons for this?

The only drawback is that to aggregate results from multiple pages a large number of requests is needed, which is obviously quickly exceeding the limit of 10 requests per 10 seconds.

Comment: @tsw_mik It's not supported.